# Count multiple values with jquery

Tags: jquery, input, count

I am trying to create counting function with jquery.

I have multiple sets of inputs with numbers determined, something like:

```
<input class="price" type="hidden" name="price" value="4">
<input class="count" type="text" name="count" maxlength="4">
```

I want to create script that will count all inputs, eg.

```
 (price * count) + (price * count) etc..
```

So far i came up with this script, which multiplies and displays only one input

```
$('.count').blur(function() {
    var amount = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.price');
    var result = parseFloat((price).val());
    var money = (amount * result)
    $('.money').text(money);
});
```

Comment: Could you add a more complete HTML example - we need to see how your `.price` and `.count` elements are grouped in order to iterate over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop inside your blur handler like

```
var $counts = $('.count').blur(function () {
    var money = 0;
    $counts.each(function () {
        money += (+this.value * $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').val()) || 0
    });

    $('.money').text(money);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0nygLn6L/)